# The logo looks fine in codepen but is too big in outlook (email template)

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an email template (HTML with inline CSS), the template has a logo with a fixed width and height (px). For some reason, after I received an email with this template, the logo took up the entire width of the page. I tried to add`!Important` in width and height properties, but it doesn't work.

It looks right in editor, but not in outlook.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Here is the code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>New Assignment</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* reset */
    article,
    aside,
    details,
    figcaption,
    figure,
    footer,
    header,
    hgroup,
    nav,
    section,
    summary {
      display: block
    }

    .logo {
      width: 200px !important;
      height: 200px !important;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
      filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    }

    audio,
    canvas,
    video {
      display: inline-block;
      *display: inline;
      *zoom: 1
    }

    audio:not([controls]) {
      display: none;
      height: 0
    }

    [hidden] {
      display: none
    }

    html {
      font-size: 100%;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%
    }

    html,
    button,
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
      font-family: sans-serif
    }

    body {
      margin: 0
    }

    a:focus {
      outline: thin dotted
    }

    a:active,
    a:hover {
      outline: 0
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 2em;
      margin: 0 0.67em 0
    }

    h2 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      margin: 0 0 .83em 0
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 1.17em;
      margin: 1em 0
    }

    h4 {
      font-size: 1em;
      margin: 1.33em 0
    }

    h5 {
      font-size: .83em;
      margin: 1.67em 0
    }

    h6 {
      font-size: .75em;
      margin: 2.33em 0
    }

    abbr[title] {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted
    }

    b,
    strong {
      font-weight: bold
    }

    blockquote {
      margin: 1em 40px
    }

    dfn {
      font-style: italic
    }

    mark {
      background: #ff0;
      color: #000
    }

    p,
    pre {
      margin: 1em 0
    }

    code,
    kbd,
    pre,
    samp {
      font-family: monospace, serif;
      _font-family: 'courier new', monospace;
      font-size: 1em
    }

    pre {
      white-space: pre;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      word-wrap: break-word
    }

    q {
      quotes: none
    }

    q:before,
    q:after {
      content: '';
      content: none
    }

    small {
      font-size: 75%
    }

    sub,
    sup {
      font-size: 75%;
      line-height: 0;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: baseline
    }

    sup {
      top: -0.5em
    }

    sub {
      bottom: -0.25em
    }

    dl,
    menu,
    ol,
    ul {
      margin: 1em 0
    }

    dd {
      margin: 0 0 0 40px
    }

    menu,
    ol,
    ul {
      padding: 0 0 0 40px
    }

    nav ul,
    nav ol {
      list-style: none;
      list-style-image: none
    }

    img {
      border: 0;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic
    }

    svg:not(:root) {
      overflow: hidden
    }

    figure {
      margin: 0
    }

    form {
      margin: 0
    }

    fieldset {
      border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
      margin: 0 2px;
      padding: .35em .625em .75em
    }

    legend {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      white-space: normal;
      *margin-left: -7px
    }

    button,
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
      font-size: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      *vertical-align: middle
    }

    button,
    input {
      line-height: normal
    }

    button,
    html input[type="button"],
    input[type="reset"],
    input[type="submit"] {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      cursor: pointer;
      *overflow: visible
    }

    button[disabled],
    input[disabled] {
      cursor: default
    }

    input[type="checkbox"],
    input[type="radio"] {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      *height: 13px;
      *width: 13px
    }

    input[type="search"] {
      -webkit-appearance: textfield;
      -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box
    }

    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
      -webkit-appearance: none
    }

    button::-moz-focus-inner,
    input::-moz-focus-inner {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0
    }

    textarea {
      overflow: auto;
      vertical-align: top
    }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0
    }

    /* custom client-specific styles including styles for different online clients */
    .ReadMsgBody {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
    }

    /* hotmail / outlook.com */
    .ExternalClass,
    .ExternalClass p,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td,
    .ExternalClass div {
      line-height: 100%;
    }

    /* hotmail / outlook.com */
    table,
    td {
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }

    /* Outlook */
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }

    /* Outlook */
    img {
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
      display: block;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* IExplorer */
    body,
    table,
    td,
    p,
    a,
    li,
    blockquote {
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      font-weight: normal !important;
    }

    .ExternalClass td[class="ecxflexibleContainerBox"] h3 {
      padding-top: 10px !important;
    }

    /* hotmail */
    /* email template styles */
    h1 {
      display: block;
      font-size: 26px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 100%;
    }

    h2 {
      display: block;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 120%;
    }

    h3 {
      display: block;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 110%;
    }

    h4 {
      display: block;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 100%;
    }

    .flexibleImage {
      height: auto;
    }

    table[class=flexibleContainerCellDivider] {
      padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      padding-top: 0 !important;
    }

    body,
    #bodyTbl {
      background-color: #E1E1E1;
    }

    #emailHeader {
      background-color: #E1E1E1;
    }

    #emailBody {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    #emailFooter {
      background-color: #E1E1E1;
    }

    .textContent {
      color: #8B8B8B;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 125%;
      text-align: Left;
    }

    .textContent a {
      color: #205478;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .emailButton {
      background-color: #205478;
      border-collapse: separate;
    }

    .buttonContent {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 100%;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .buttonContent a {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      border: 0 !important;
    }

    #invisibleIntroduction {
      display: none;
      display: none !important;
    }

    /* hide the introduction text */
    /* other framework hacks and overrides */
    span[class=ios-color-hack] a {
      color: #275100 !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
    }

    /* Remove all link colors in IOS (below are duplicates based on the color preference) */
    span[class=ios-color-hack2] a {
      color: #205478 !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
    }

    span[class=ios-color-hack3] a {
      color: #8B8B8B !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
    }

    /* phones and sms */
    .a[href^="tel"],
    a[href^="sms"] {
      text-decoration: none !important;
      color: #606060 !important;
      pointer-events: none !important;
      cursor: default !important;
    }

    .mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
    .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
      text-decoration: none !important;
      color: #606060 !important;
      pointer-events: auto !important;
      cursor: default !important;
    }

    /* responsive styles */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      body {
        width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 100% !important;
      }

      table[id="emailHeader"],
      table[id="emailBody"],
      table[id="emailFooter"],
      table[class="flexibleContainer"] {
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      td[class="flexibleContainerBox"],
      td[class="flexibleContainerBox"] table {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }

      td[class="imageContent"] img {
        height: auto !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }

      img[class="flexibleImage"] {
        height: auto !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }

      img[class="flexibleImageSmall"] {
        height: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
      }

      table[class="flexibleContainerBoxNext"] {
        padding-top: 10px !important;
      }

      table[class="emailButton"] {
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      td[class="buttonContent"] {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }

      td[class="buttonContent"] a {
        padding: 15px !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!--
      MS Outlook custom styles
    -->
  <!--[if mso 12]>
      <style type="text/css">
        .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
  <!--[if mso 14]>
      <style type="text/css">
        .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body bgcolor="#E1E1E1" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
  <center style="background-color:#E1E1E1;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTbl" style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">

          <table bgcolor="#E1E1E1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" id="emailHeader">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">

                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">

                      <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">

                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="middle" id="invisibleIntroduction" class="flexibleContainerBox" style="display:none;display:none !important;">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="left" class="textContent">
                                        <div style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#828282;text-align:center;line-height:120%;">
                                          Project Template
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" id="emailBody">

            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="color:#FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#009999">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="textContent">
                                  <img class="logo" style="width: 200px !important; height: 200px !important; margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 20px; -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg" alt="Logo">
                                  <h1 style="color:#FFFFFF;line-height:100%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:35px;font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center;"> {{pageName}} New Joiner </h1>

                                  <h2 style="text-align:center;font-weight:normal;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:23px;margin-bottom:10px;color:#FCC310;line-height:135%;">{{userName}}</h2>
                                  <div style="text-align:center;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;color:#FFFFFF;line-height:135%;">{{userName}} wants to join your page.</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">

                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td valign="top" class="textContent">
                                        <h3 style="color:#5F5F5F;line-height:125%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:3px;text-align:left;">{{userName}}</h3>
                                        <div style="text-align:left;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:3px;color:#5F5F5F;line-height:135%;">Hi! I would like to join your page {{pageName}}! Please accept my request.</div>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>

                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" class="emailButton" style="background-color: #009999;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" valign="middle" class="buttonContent" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;">
                                        <a style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:135%;" href="{{link}}" target="_blank">Open Request</a>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>

                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>

          <!-- footer -->
          <table bgcolor="#E1E1E1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" id="emailFooter">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#E1E1E1">

                                  <div style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#828282;text-align:center;line-height:120%;">
                                    <div>Copyright &#169; 2022. All rights reserved.</div>
                                    <div>You can also see your notifications in the <a href="https://app.omegaconstructionmanagement.com/profile" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#828282;"><span style="color:#828282;">Application</span></a></div>
                                  </div>

                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- // end of footer -->

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Added code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to email!

Outlook looks to the width and height attributes, rather than the inline styles. So you don't need !important, either.

```
<img class="logo" width="200" height="200" <!-- added attributes --> 
style="width: 200px !important; height: 200px !important; margin: 0 auto;
```

remove those !importants. Outlook will generally remove anything with !important inline, not that that matters for this case.

```
margin-bottom: 20px; -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
```

it's important to note that Outlook sticks to the original design for HTML elements, so img is inline, and margins won't work. Wrap it in a `<p>` and put the margin on that, or use padding on the `<td>`

```
filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));"
```

This should be considered a progressive enhancement, as it will only work on some email clients. https://www.caniemail.com is you best friend, i.e. https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-filter/

```
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg"
```

SVG support is limited. Use a PNG. See  https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-svg/

Many email programs will, in general, only use HTML4 and CSS2, but you may use later technology for improving experience in clients like Apple Mail--as long as you have a fallback.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is super helpful and informative!